# hide and show panel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wonder how can i hide the attached panel in a way that only the red button to be shown on the left side of the browser's window and when i click on the red button to appear the whole panel. If i click again on the red button, the panel to disappear again on the left side of the browser's window?

[image: panel]

I know i should use absolute positioning related to a relative positioned wrapper div, but that's all my idea...

```
<div class="wrapper"><div id="panel"></div><!-- #panel --><p>content</p></div><!-- .wrapper -->

.wrapper {position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; height: 500px;}

#panel {position: absolute; left: -150px; top: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a very simple example, it uses the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to handle the showing  and hiding:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#click').click(function()
{
    $("#panel").animate({width:'toggle'},500);       
});
```

[**Working Demo Available here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/J8U25/)

**CSS (*from demo*):**

```
//The content panel
#panel
{
     height: 500px;
     width: 200px;
     background: black;
     float: left;
     display: none;    
     color: white;
     font-size: xx-large;
}

//The tab
#click
{
     height: 50px;
     width: 25px;
     background: red;
     float: left; 
     margin-top: 200px;
}
```

**Related HTML:**

```
<div id='panel'>[Put your content here]</div>
<div id='click'>
```

Comment: useful answer, thumbs up. and as it was the first correct answer, i'll choose it as the accepted answer. thanks a lot, now i have a clue about the idea of this panel hiding stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Check out jQuery UI effects for what you're trying to acheive:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 2):

The provide solution is very basic and is targeted soley towards the `onClick` event and interaction.

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">Content
</div>
<div id="tab">+</div>
```

CSS:

```
#panel { width: 300px; height: 200px; background: #000; display: none; float: left; }
#tab { width: 50px; background: #FF0000; height: 50px; float: left; text-align: center;}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#tab").click(function(){
    $("#panel").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```

Working example available at: http://jsfiddle.net/5cdgw/

Answer (score 2):

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32Qud/)

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {position:absolute;left:-200px;width:300px;height:400px;}
#panel {background:red;position:absolute;right:0;top:30px;width:100px;height:150px;cursor:pointer}
.wrapper > p {background:#000;color:#fff;width:200px;height:400px;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var isOpen = false;
$('#panel').click(function() {
    if (isOpen) {
        $(this).parent().stop(true, true).animate({left: '-200'}, 'fast');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().stop(true, true).animate({left: '0'}, 'fast');
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
});
```